# Unable to use FTP Passive Mode on CentOS 7 (running in Docker container)

Tags: ftp, docker, centos-7

I've got a CentOS 7 machine, running inside a Docker container.

I'm developing an application that will have to connect to an FTP Server, and download some files - to do that, I need to set my FTP connection to passive mode. Unfortunately, this machine seems unable to use FTP Passive Mode at all. Whatever client I try to use, I always obtain the same error:

```
ftp> open ftp
Connected to ftp (172.18.0.8).
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)
Name (ftp:root): admin
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> ls
227 Entering Passive Mode (10,105,125,200,185,104).
ftp: connect: No route to host
```

Here the logs from the FTP server:

```
Tue Jun 19 12:36:32 2018 [pid 20820] CONNECT: Client "172.18.0.7"
Tue Jun 19 12:36:32 2018 [pid 20820] FTP response: Client "172.18.0.7", "220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)"
Tue Jun 19 12:36:34 2018 [pid 20820] FTP command: Client "172.18.0.7", "USER admin"
Tue Jun 19 12:36:34 2018 [pid 20820] [admin] FTP response: Client "172.18.0.7", "331 Please specify the password."
Tue Jun 19 12:36:38 2018 [pid 20820] [admin] FTP command: Client "172.18.0.7", "PASS <password>"
Tue Jun 19 12:36:38 2018 [pid 20819] [admin] OK LOGIN: Client "172.18.0.7"
Tue Jun 19 12:36:38 2018 [pid 20821] [admin] FTP response: Client "172.18.0.7", "230 Login successful."
Tue Jun 19 12:36:38 2018 [pid 20821] [admin] FTP command: Client "172.18.0.7", "SYST"
Tue Jun 19 12:36:38 2018 [pid 20821] [admin] FTP response: Client "172.18.0.7", "215 UNIX Type: L8"
Tue Jun 19 12:36:43 2018 [pid 20821] [admin] FTP command: Client "172.18.0.7", "PASV"
Tue Jun 19 12:36:43 2018 [pid 20821] [admin] FTP response: Client "172.18.0.7", "227 Entering Passive Mode (10,105,125,200,185,104)."
```

Using the same credentials, hostname (10.105.125.200 is an address inside my local network) and port (21), I have no trouble using passive mode from other machines that also run in Docker. For example, on a Debian machine, this problem does not occur.

I've tried the following fix: https://linuxconfig.org/rhel7-ftp-server-error-ftp-connect-no-route-to-host-solution but since the machine runs on Docker, it does not have the full possibilities of a raw machine (at least, not out of the box)-> For example, I'm unable to run iptables.

I've also found suggestions that maybe the CentOS firewall is blocking something - but, the problem of the machine being inside Docker also stopped me here, since I can't use basic programs like systemctl.